# Como puedo compilar con gulp-sass?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sass, gulp

Estoy creando un proyecto con gulp-sass, es la segunda vez que trabajo con nodejs y tengo un problema, al intentar compilar el código me da un error, he visto bastantes y variadas formas de arreglarlo en la red, pero por desgracia ninguna me ha funcionado, os dejo el código para ver si alguien encuentra el error, gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Este es el error:

```
[12:42:49] Requiring external module babel-register
[12:43:09] Using gulpfile /opt/lampp/htdocs/faster/wp-content/themes/jbfaster/gulpfile.babel.js
[12:43:09] Starting 'default'...
[12:43:09] Starting 'server'...
[12:43:09] Starting 'css'...
Error in plugin "gulp-sass"
Message:
    
gulp-sass 5 does not have a default Sass compiler; please set one yourself.
Both the `sass` and `node-sass` packages are permitted.
For example, in your gulpfile:

  var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

[12:43:09] The following tasks did not complete: default, server, css
[12:43:09] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Intente lo que me decía la consola, pero al hacerlo así me da un error de que con mi versión solo se acepta el método import. Con otra versión inferior tampoco me funcionaba.

El código de mi archivo gulpfile:

```
import gulp from 'gulp'  
import browserSync from 'browser-sync'
import plumber from 'gulp-plumber'
import sass from 'gulp-sass' 
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps'
import autoprefixer from 'gulp-autoprefixer'
import cleanCSS from 'gulp-clean-css'
import browserify from 'browserify'
import babelify from 'babelify'
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream' 
import buffer from'vinyl-buffer'
import jsmin from 'gulp-jsmin' 
import imagemin from 'gulp-imagemin'
import wpPot from 'gulp-wp-pot'
import sort from 'gulp-sort' 

const reload = browserSync.reload,
reloadFiles = [
    './script.js',
    './style.css',
    './**/*.php'
],
proxyOptions = {
    proxy: 'localhost:8080/faster/',
    notify: false
}

gulp.task('server',()=>browserSync.init(reloadFiles,proxyOptions))

gulp.task('css',()=>{
     gulp.src('./css/style.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps:true}))
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers:['last 2 versions']}))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./css/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
})

gulp.task('default',gulp.parallel('server','css'),()=>{
    gulp.watch('.css/**/*.+(scss|css)',('css')})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mensaje de error te esta intentando explicar que no has inicializado correctamente el paquete. Puntualmente señala que una forma de hacerlo es:

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
```

Dado que estas usando `import`, la forma de hacerlo sería:

```
import dartSass from 'sass';
import gulpSass from 'gulp-sass';
const sass = gulpSass( dartSass );
```

---

Fuente: [gulp-sass > Importing it into your project](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass#importing-it-into-your-project)